# How to generate values for all fields including required fields in a protobuf message

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I have a big protobuf message. I'd like to set all the fields of the message including optional and required fields.
Is there any way to do it without using the set_field_name() for each field in the message

Comment: You can take a look at protobuf Reflection.